# Generated subspaces with a minimal number of generators

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vector-fields, invariant-subspace

$C = { (x, y, z) ∈ R
^3
| x+y+z = 0}$ .How to write C as generated subspaces with a minimal number of generators ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(x, y, -x-y)=x(1, 0, -1)+y(0, 1, -1)$

The vectors $(1, 0, -1), (0, 1, -1)$ span C.